# Failure to install webR package, needed to make PieDonut charts

Tags: r, macos, package

I am having issues installing the 'webr' package in R, which is necessary to use the PieDonut function to make beautiful multi-level pie charts.

I have followed the instructions on this website, which demonstrates how to install the packages and work with it. https://rpubs.com/cardiomoon/398623.

However, when installing the package 'webr' it says:

```
> devtools::install_github("cardiomoon/webr")
Downloading GitHub repo cardiomoon/webr@HEAD
── R CMD build ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/ml/s3851ylx2rv93hwzkjzfgnwh0000gn/T/Rtmp1yWHbr/remotesa73745291d/cardiomoon-webr-6e411bd/DESCRIPTION’ (371ms)
─  preparing ‘webr’:
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
   Omitted ‘LazyData’ from DESCRIPTION
─  building ‘webr_0.1.6.tar.gz’
   
* installing *source* package ‘webr’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/devEMF/libs/devEMF.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/devEMF/libs/devEMF.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libXft.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/devEMF/libs/devEMF.so
  Reason: image not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... asNamespace -> loadNamespace -> library.dynam -> dyn.load
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘webr’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/webr’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/ml/s3851ylx2rv93hwzkjzfgnwh0000gn/T//Rtmp1yWHbr/filea734d8e32a5/webr_0.1.6.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status1yWHbr/filea734d8e32a5/webr_0.1.6.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: That type of error is typically preceded by other warnings or error messages. Please [edit] your question to include the command you used to install it (`install.packages("webr")`?) and all output before it returns you to the R prompt (or exits).

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: the problem should disappear if you install the newest version of devEMF from CRAN and try again:

```
install.packages("devEMF")
```

Longer explanation: this error arose from a dependency of a dependency (webr uses rrtable; rrtable uses devEMF) that had a bug that affected Mac users who installed binary versions of the package.  This bug should be fixed in devEMF v4.3-1, which is available on CRAN now.  Running the `install.packages` command above will update devEMF to this version with the fix.